# When do I need to add <?> when creating generic objects?

Tags: java, generics

let me give you an example (client-server communication), let's say we have the following class:

```
public class Message<Data, From extends Connectable, To extends Connectable>
```

Connectable is an interface that both the client and server implements.
My question is when creating an instance of Message do I have to add `<?, ?, ?>` to the type?

```
Message<?, ?, ?> m = new Message<>(...);
```

or

```
Message m = new Message<>(...);
```

I know `<?>` is a wildcard shortcut for `<? extends Object>` I just don't get when do I have to add this? Is there any difference? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 0):

You never *need* to add `<?>`, but in new code you always *should* add it (for generic classes). Basically, the `<?>` tells the compiler that you know about generics and want the strict type checking that comes with it.

However, usually you will not use `<?>` but a more specific type parameter:

```
Message<String, SourceConnectable, TargetConnectable> m = new Message<String, SourceConnectable, TargetConnectable>(...);
```

or, employing type inference features of newer Java versions:

```
Message<String, SourceConnectable, TargetConnectable> m = new Message<>(...); // Java 1.7+
var m = new Message<String, SourceConnectable, TargetConnectable>(...); // Java 10+
```

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, that "in new code" should also apply to that, of course. But I removed the sentence. It doesn't really say what I wanted to say with it, and it wasn't necessary for the answer.